# RuntimeError: error during nfq_bind_pf

Tags: python, linux, networking, iptables

I am getting the following error when I try to use python-nfqueue. My code is

```
import logging

l=logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime")
l.setLevel(49)

import os,sys,nfqueue,socket
from scapy.all import *

q = nfqueue.queue()
    q.open()
    q.bind(socket.AF_INET)
```

I get an RuntimeError: error during nfq_bind_pf during the last line. I am using python 2.7 and Ubuntu 12.04. Also

```
cat /proc/net/netfilter/nf_queue
```

returns

```
0 NONE

1 NONE

2 nf_queue

3 NONE
```